# how can i get install raspberry pi os on hyper-v

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi-desktop, virtualization

I am trying to install raspberry pi os on hyper-v using '2022-07-01-raspios-bullseye-i386.iso.
After the VM starts, the OS install starts.  When I try to connect it starts the OS install.
Using either command line or graphical install, the os configures and gets the the point where it reboots.  After the reboot and reconnect, the os install starts over.

So I am in a continual loop of the OS trying to install.  In graphical, it always comes back to the:

- Welcome to Raspberry Pi Desktop
- Before you start using it, there are a few things to set up
- Press Next to get started.

The VM configuration is:

- start memory    1024MB
- Startup memory  1024MB
- Minimum memory  512MB
- Max memory 1048576MB
- Assigned memory 26656MB
- Memory demand 27189
- Memory status  Warning

I am running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit ver 22H2, 32GB memory and lots of free disk space

Help gratefully accepted
Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about Pi Desktop for PC / Mac

Comment: Ok perhaps I am new to this forum but why is this question inappropriate?  It has to do with the raspian OS which is part of the pi community.  I am retired and do this to try to keep my mind agile.  I have 8 raspberry's pis and multiple other microprocessors  I am a retired Ph.D. computer engineer.  I work hard to answer questions for myself.  I have built several commercial embedded systems using bare metal programming (no operating system).  This one I have as yet been unable to crack.  So please help or explain where I should go and why

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour. Your question is about Pi Desktop for PC and Mac. That is *not* the same as PiOS. It's Debian with a Pi flavoured desktop. It's also not for Pi hardware and thus it's off-topic.

Comment: Gee thanks Dirk-- shows up as Raspian.  Downloads from official Pi site.  Part of Pi eco system.  Have to agree to disagree

Comment: Sorry you are still wrong. the tutorial points to https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/ which is NOT PiOS. It's Debian with a \Pi flavoured desktop and is not compatible with Pi hardware and thus off topic according to the rules of this Pi SE

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work -- many tries
Installed VM with hyper-v using tutorial on https://www.avoiderrors.com/how-to-install-raspbian-os-on-hyper-v/

when the RPi image boots it will loop in the install unless you select skip updates.  If you don't, you will get another chance soon

Comment: Sorry you are still wrong. the tutorial points to https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/ which is NOT PiOS. It's Debian with a \Pi flavoured desktop and is not compatible with Pi hardware and thus off topic according to the rules of this Pi SE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).